# Increase image sizes get from cache android

Tags: android, performance, bitmap

Hi I download images from url & save them in cache. Then load those images from cache into carousel view.

but the problem is when phone resolution(720X1124) is high image size become small.

Here I give the code of images save & show them from cach...

```
 private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
    {
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);


        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(300000000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(300000000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream inputstream=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream outputstream = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(inputstream, outputstream);
            outputstream.close();
            conn.disconnect();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Throwable ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           if(ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
               memoryCache.clear();
           return null;
        }
    }

   public void getDimension(int width,int height){
       widthScreen=width;
       heightScreen=height;

   }
    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 120000000; // 1.2MP

            BitmapFactory.Options scaleOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            scaleOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            FileInputStream stream1=new FileInputStream(f);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1,null,scaleOptions);
            stream1.close();

         // find the correct scale value as a power of 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while (scaleOptions.outWidth / scale / 2 >= widthScreen
              && scaleOptions.outHeight / scale / 2 >= heightScreen) {
              scale *= 2;
            }


           Bitmap bitmap = null;
            if (scale > 1) {
               scale--;
                // scale to max possible inSampleSize that still yields an image
                // larger than target
               scaleOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
               scaleOptions.inSampleSize = scale;
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1, null, scaleOptions);


                int width=widthScreen;
                int height=heightScreen;

                double y=height;
                double x=width;


                Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, (int) x, 
                   (int) y, true);
                bitmap.recycle();
                bitmap = scaledBitmap;

                System.gc();
            } else {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1);
            }
            if((widthScreen>=450)&& (heightScreen>=750) ) {
                sample=1;
            }
            else{
                sample=2;
            }
            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options scalOption = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            scalOption.inSampleSize=sample;
            FileInputStream stream2=new FileInputStream(f);
            Bitmap bitMap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, scalOption);
            stream2.close();
            return bitMap;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

how to increase the image sizes according phone resolution. I have tired more days to overcome this problem. But it doesn't work. So give me right instruction.......
thanks............

Comment: You need to define your requirement more clearly: do you want to increase the dimension of the image to be downloaded (i.e. larger image for larger screens), or just increase the dimension of the Bitmap created from the same image (i.e. scaling image to fit screen)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public int  calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;


        int inSampleSize = 1;
        if (height < reqHeight || width < reqWidth) {
            if (width > height) {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            } else {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
            }
        }
        return inSampleSize;
    }
```

put this method in my code and call this method as following way ,

```
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try {
            // decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            FileInputStream stream1 = new FileInputStream(f);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1, null, o);
            stream1.close();


             Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
             // matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
              matrix.postRotate(45);
            // decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            //calculateInSampleSize1(o, widthScreen,heightScreen);

            o2.inSampleSize=calculateInSampleSize(o, widthScreen,heightScreen);;
            FileInputStream stream2 = new FileInputStream(f);
            o2.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);

            stream2.close();
            return bitmap;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your layout for the different screen sizes / resolutions.
See [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html).

Answer (score 1):

try to load images with this [image loader library](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)